# div over map still allowing drag/click on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, leaflet, mapbox

edit: solved this myself.

```
function disableMap() {
    map.dragging.disable();
    map.touchZoom.disable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.disable();
    map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
    map.boxZoom.disable();
    map.keyboard.disable();
    if (map.tap) map.tap.disable();
    console.log("map off");
}
function enableMap() {
    map.dragging.enable();
    map.touchZoom.enable();
    map.doubleClickZoom.enable();
    map.scrollWheelZoom.enable();
    map.boxZoom.enable();
    map.keyboard.enable();
    if (map.tap) map.tap.enable();
    console.log("map on");
}

$('form.filterbar').on('mouseover mousedown touchstart', function() {
    disableMap();
});

$('form.filterbar').on('mouseout mouseup touchend', function() {
    enableMap();
});
```

in CSS, set the cursor of the element so it can handle the click/touch events...

```
form.filterbar {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();`, `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` come to mind... But as you say, it's very strange that the event goes through a layer that's on top of it. These `e.` things prevent default bahaviour and bubbling on the clicked element, but as your `div` *isn't the parent or child* of the map, I don't get it... Are you sure nothing else is wrong, maybe the div isn't covering the full map on iOS?

Comment: I use map.dragging.disable(); and that disables dragging for me on iOS 8.1. To disable zoom, I'm simply setting minZoom, maxZoom, and zoom to the same value. Did you try stepping into any of those disable calls or stepping into any of the leaflet event handlers?

Comment: yep. didn't seem to work. I think the issue I'm having is where to hook those calls - "click" and related events aren't the same on iOS - what did you use? PS the div is a child of the map but rendered to be absolutely positioned / z-index over the map ... like constant controls.

Comment: figured it out, and I knew this so it's my dumb mistake. the element I was using for .on (form.filterbar) was not "clickable" -- in other words, it didn't have the pointer set to cursor. see above edit for working code.